# Как проверить доступность исполняемого файла к запуску?

Tags: c#, windows, файловая-система

Суть вопроса: Генерирую `*.bat` файл. Если его запускать вручную - всё работает, если идти по коду из под отладчика - тоже всё работает правильно. Но если запускать код без точки останова `*.bat` не запускается.

Код создания файла:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fullpaath, true);
                           
sw.WriteLine("@echo off");
sw.WriteLine("setlocal");
sw.WriteLine(">nul 2>&1 net session&&goto run");
sw.WriteLine("if /i \"%~1\"==\"yes\" goto run");
sw.WriteLine("if /i \"%~1\"==\"\" set \"args=noparam\"");
sw.WriteLine("set \"file=%~f0\"");
sw.WriteLine("set \"args=% * %args%\"");
sw.WriteLine("set file=\"\"%file:\"=%\"\"");
sw.WriteLine("set args=%args:\"=\"\"%");
sw.WriteLine("> \"%temp%" + "\\" + "uac.vbs\" echo set objShell=CreateObject^(\"Shell.Application\"^)");
sw.WriteLine(">> \"%temp%" + "\\" + "uac.vbs\" echo objShell.ShellExecute \"cmd\", \"/c \"\"%file% \"\"yes\"\" %args%\"\"\", , \"runas\", 1");
sw.WriteLine("cscript /nologo /e:vbscript \"%temp%" + "\\" + "uac.vbs\"");
sw.WriteLine("exit /b");
sw.WriteLine(":run");
sw.WriteLine("> nul 2>&1 del \"%temp%" + "\\" + "uac.vbs\"");
sw.WriteLine("cd /d \"%~dp0\"");
sw.WriteLine("title %cd%");
sw.WriteLine("shift");
sw.WriteLine("if \"%~1\"==\"noparam\" shift");
sw.WriteLine("");
sw.WriteLine("sc delete Starter");
sw.WriteLine("timeout 2");
sw.WriteLine("PowerShell stop-service Starter");
sw.WriteLine("timeout 2");
sw.WriteLine("taskkill /IM java.exe /F");
sw.Close();
sw.Dispose();

/*  DateTime started = DateTime.Now;
while (sw.BaseStream!=null)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(started).TotalSeconds > 20)
        break;
}*/
    bool a = false;

    while (!a)
    {
        try
        {
            var rf  = File.OpenRead(fullpaath);
            rf.Close();
            rf.Dispose();
            a = true;
        }
        catch
        { a = false; }
    }
```

`while (sw.BaseStream!=null` - проверял что поток закрылся и освободил файл (sw.Close(); sw.Dispose(); с той же целью), не помогло.
`rf = File.OpenRead(fullpaath)` - проверяю что никто файл не держит (антивирус например) - не помогло.
Антивирус отключал (Вин10 - проверка в реалтайм) - не помогло, да и не вариант, у конечного пользователя он  может и работать.
Батник нужен чтобы не давать (не просить) админские права всему проекту (нужна разовая операция по удалению службы).
Запускаю через `Process`. в методе запуска вызываются разные батники, созданные ранее, без проблем всё отрабатывает. Создаваемый бат-файл - копия существующего (создаётся на случай удаления файла).
То есть единственная мысль: что то всё таки держит созданный файл какое то время и не даёт ему запуститься. Но что и как проверить - голову сломал.
Буду благодарен за любые идеи куда копать.

P.S. `Thread.Sleep` не предлагать, по причине, что быстродействие машины конечного пользователя не известно.  Нужно именно понять, что файл можно запускать.
P.P.S батник просит для себя права администратора, код взят из интернета.

Метод запуска:

```
public static bool Action_GSS(string action, string workdirectory)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(workdirectory+"\\GeoServer\\" + action + ".bat"))
        //если батника нет то создадим его
        { MakeBat(action, workdirectory); }
        if (File.Exists(workdirectory + "\\GeoServer\\" + action + ".bat"))
        {
            Process Geocalcinstall = new Process(); //создаем новый процесс
            Geocalcinstall.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            
            Geocalcinstall.StartInfo.FileName = workdirectory + "\\GeoServer\\" + action + ".bat"; //указываем исполняемый файл (программу) для запуска

            Geocalcinstall.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            try
            {
                Geocalcinstall.Start(); //пытаемся запустить процесс
            }
            catch (Win32Exception e)
            {
                MainWindow.logger.Error(e.Message + " "+ action + " failed");
                return false; //Ничего не делаем, потому что пользователь, возможно, нажал кнопку "Нет" в ответ на вопрос о запуске программы в окне предупреждения UAC (для Windows 7)
            }

            Geocalcinstall.WaitForExit(3000);


            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            MainWindow.logger.Error(" bat not found, uninstal filed");
            return false; }

    }
```

Попробовал вместо записи копировать бат-файл из другой директории. Происходит тоже самое - отрабатывает 1-я команда и таймаут, после этого окно cmd закрывается. Изменил код запуска процесса :
ProcessStartInfo Geocalcinstall = new ProcessStartInfo(); //создаем новый процесс
Geocalcinstall.UseShellExecute = false;

```
            Geocalcinstall.FileName = workdirectory + "\\GeoServer\\" + action + ".bat"; //указываем исполняемый файл (программу) для запуска
            Geocalcinstall.WorkingDirectory = workdirectory + "\\GeoServer";
          //  Geocalcinstall.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            try
            {
                
                Process.Start(Geocalcinstall); //пытаемся запустить процесс
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MainWindow.logger.Error(e.Message + " "+ action + " failed");
                return false; //Ничего не делаем, потому что пользователь, возможно, нажал кнопку "Нет" в ответ на вопрос о запуске программы в окне предупреждения UAC (для Windows 7)
            }
```

Но это так же не помогло.
То есть если батник запустить мышкой - он отрабатывает полностью, если из кода - то первые 2 строчки.
Может у Process есть какой-то внутренний таймер ? Или я запуск делаю как то не так ?
Просто уже хочется докопаться до сути .......

Comment: А если добавить `sw.Flush();`? Хотя и `Close`, и `Dispose` сами должны делать сброс буферов.

Comment: Покажите код, как запускаете батник. Потому что тут проблем не видно.

Comment: Alexander Petrov   функция без проблем запускает ЭТОТ же бат-файл, если трассируешь под отладчиком, то есть если есть паузы между вызовами методов, либо если бат-файл был сделан заранее

Comment: Alexander Petrov  sw.Flush(); не дал эффекта

Comment: `if (!File.Exists` и `if (File.Exists` - может, компилятор оптимизирует код и выкидывает вторую проверку? Это декомпилятором смотреть нужно.

Comment: Или просто ради теста вставьте между ифами какую-нибудь операцию. Например, запись в лог. Тогда компилятор точно ничего не выкинет.

Comment: 1) Добавьте pause при старте и запустите выполнение с видимой консолью(а возможно даже лучше из под cmd.exe `new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + batFileName)`). Если батник действительно не запускается окно не появится. 2) Не совсем понятно почему обрабатывается только `Win32Exception`. Может исключение "ускользает"?

Answer (score 0):

По пробуйте использовать команду `Task.Delay(1000);` чтобы сделать задержку и еще перейдите в вкладку `Проект -> Свойства -> Сборка` и уберите галку `Оптимизировать код`

Можешь еще такой вариант по пробывать:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
            fullpaath,
           new string[] {
            "@echo off",
               "setlocal",
               ">nul 2>&1 net session&&goto run",
               "if /i \"%~1\"==\"yes\" goto run",
               "if /i \"%~1\"==\"\" set \"args=noparam\"",
               "set \"file=%~f0\"",
               "set \"args=% * %args%\"",
               "set file=\"\"%file:\"=%\"\"",
               "set args=%args:\"=\"\"%",
               "> \"%temp%" + "\\" + "uac.vbs\" echo set objShell=CreateObject^(\"Shell.Application\"^)",
               ">> \"%temp%" + "\\" + "uac.vbs\" echo objShell.ShellExecute \"cmd\", \"/c \"\"%file% \"\"yes\"\" %args%\"\"\", , \"runas\", 1",
               "cscript /nologo /e:vbscript \"%temp%" + "\\" + "uac.vbs\"",
               "exit /b",
               ":run",
               "> nul 2>&1 del \"%temp%" + "\\" + "uac.vbs\"",
               "cd /d \"%~dp0\"",
               "title %cd%",
               "shift",
               "if \"%~1\"==\"noparam\" shift",
               "",
               "sc delete Starter",
               "timeout 2",
               "PowerShell stop-service Starter",
               "timeout 2",
               "taskkill /IM java.exe /F"
        });
```

Comment: оптимизация коды выключена.

Comment: Попробовал File.WriteAllLines - никаких изменений....

Comment: проверка на наличие монопольного доступа вроде помогла   var fs = new FileStream(fullpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);, но теперь другая проблема - отрабатывают только 2 первый команды.

Comment: Geocalcinstall.WaitForExit(3000);
как бы напрашивается что просто времени не хватает, но например  Geocalcinstall.WaitForExit(10000);
даёт тот же самый результат

Comment: @Dmitrii , Значит не позволяет дальше считывать. Пробывали еще вот так?

`if (!File.Exists(path)) {
  using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) {
   sw.WriteLine("@echo off");
   sw.WriteLine("setlocal");
   sw.WriteLine(">nul 2>&1 net session&&goto run");
 }
}`

Comment: @Dmitrii, Это освободит всё ресурсы и файл должен стать доступен. Есть еще костыльный метод в плане создавать копию и её запускать.

Comment: В общем коллеги, Process закрывается потому что команда в батнике вызывает ошибку. Видимо надо как то указать Process что бы игнорировал ошибки и всё будет ок.